# Array index of bound exception in parse

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to get the object saved in parse cloud but it's giving me

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

the code is:

```
      private void parsingTask() {
    //po=new ParseObject("LatLng");
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query=ParseQuery.getQuery("LatLng");
    query.whereEqualTo("imei_code","357146054169800");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> latlanglist, ParseException e) {
            if(e==null){
        String firstItemId=latlanglist.get(0).getObjectId();
        lat=latlanglist.get(0).getString("latitude");
        lang=latlanglist.get(0).getString("longitude");
        e1.setText(lat);
        e2.setText(lang);
        e3.setText(firstItemId);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Found the New Location:\nLatitude:"+lat+
                    "\nLongitude:"+lang+"\nObjectID:"+firstItemId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else{

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error was found\n"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }


        }
    });
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

the logcat output:

```
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.robotrackerserver.MainActivity$1.done(MainActivity.java:43)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.parse.Parse$6$1.run(Parse.java:973)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-15 14:34:21.064: E/AndroidRuntime(10986):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 14:34:21.134: D/dalvikvm(10986): GC_CONCURRENT freed 311K, 15% free 7079K/8327K, paused 21ms+4ms, total 118ms
```

Comment: please send your logcat output

Comment: what if the list is empty? then you just try to get the first element and it crashes. use `if(latlanglist != null && !latlanglist.isEmpty())`  before `latlanglist.get(0)`

Comment: Included the logcat output.in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception means that the returned list, `List<ParseObject> latlanglist`, is empty. 
Instead of checking if the exception is null, you should check the constraints on the object you have to work on.

```
  if(latlanglist != null && !latlanglist.isEmpty()){

  }
```

Comment: OK but why I am unable to get the object?

Comment: there has to be a mistake in your query

Comment: Should I have to make the class wrt the class made in the parse cloud??Because every tutorial is following this aproach?I am trying to get the object directly.?

Comment: I put the condition and you were right.List is empty.

Comment: Sorry Sharky..Because the error was solved with this condition and my question was also wrt to this error.thats why I marked this correct.And I dont know that comments can be marked right or not.

Comment: Please sharky can u tell how to get colums of the table stored at parse.com?

Comment: never used parsequery - can't help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(e==null&& latlanglist!=null){
if(latlanglist.size()>0){
String firstItemId=latlanglist.get(0).getObjectId();
lat=latlanglist.get(0).getString("latitude");
lang=latlanglist.get(0).getString("longitude");
e1.setText(lat);
e2.setText(lang);
e3.setText(firstItemId);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Found the New Location:\nLatitude:"+lat+
"\nLongitude:"+lang+"\nObjectID:"+firstItemId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error was found\n"+e,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
}
```